# How to run multiple doAsync at the same time?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I am using Anko library to do some background task, I have a doAsync running in a foreground service. At the same, I am updating the recyclerview by fetching data from the database. But the problem is when the foreground service doAsync is running, the recyclerview updating doAsync is not called.

I have no clue why it's not calling, can't I run multiple doAsync at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)

doasync runs multiple tasks in a 'first in first executed'(what you explained) sequence in one background thread(not multiple threads); so like asynctask by creating multiple instances of it you're just creating multiple tasks;

you need to start a new [thread](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html) for each of your tasks if you want all the tasks to run asynchronously relative to each other;